# Windows Script Host is giving an error running JavaScript

Tags: javascript, react-native, compilation, syntax-error

I keep trying to open an `index.js` file, and even reinstalled my Windows and tried every single thing that was recommended on the Web, but I keep getting this error.

```
Script:      C:\Users\usename\foldeename\file.js
Line:        1
Char:        1
Error:       Syntax error
Code:        800A03EA
Source:      Microsoft JScript compilation error
```

Comment: When I first started JavaScript, I faced the same problem until I found out WSH doesn't support JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged `react-native`, I assume that `index.js` is a JavaScript file. Double-clicking a *.js file on Windows by default tries to run it using WSH (Windows Script Host) as a JScript file. It can't run JavaScript files. Run it with Node.js instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
yeah, I already have NodeJS

Comment: @yasamankarimi Please accept my answer if it helped so that other people can find it.

Comment: See the comment on github: https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno/issues/44#issuecomment-992299431

Comment: @yasamankarimi @ADM-IT 's comment includes a useful link on using NodeJS to run JavaScript scripts on your computer. The error shows up because when you run the file, a program called WSH tries to run it, but that program doesn't understand JavaScript. You have to right click the file and open with NodeJS, since NodeJS understands JavaScript. Windows uses WSH for `.js` files by default since it thinks it is a JScript file, which is what WSH runs.